# AWS CLI list only authorized bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have 3 buckets A, B, and C in my account. I create a policy that restricting an IAM user access a specific bucket. Here is the policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::A"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::A/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

After applied this policy to an IAM user, I tried to use `aws s3 ls` command with the credentials.

```sh
# list buckets
➜ aws s3 ls
2020-06-20 03:54:56 A
2020-06-20 03:54:56 B
2020-06-20 03:54:56 C

➜ aws s3 ls s3://A
  PER sub-foler/

➜ aws s3 ls s3://B
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

It looks like it successfully restricted the user access in buckets other than A. But the user can still see existence of other buckets such as B and C.

Is it possible to restricted the user lists only the bucket (i.e. A) which is authorized to it?

Comment: No, not possible. Either you can list all buckets or you can't, there is no in between.

Comment: No, its not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission grants the ability to list buckets in the AWS Account.

*All buckets* will be returned. It is not possible to limit *which* buckets are returned.

If you do not want the user to see the list of other buckets, then do not give them the ability to list the bucket names.

Comment: Thanks, John. However, if I remove the permission s3:ListAllMyBuckets or s3:ListBuckets, the user will no longer be able to access the objects in the specified bucket. Or do you mean another permission which is "the ability to list the bucket names"?

Comment: `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` allows users to use `aws s3 ls`, which lists the names of buckets. With that permission, they can list all names of buckets. Without that permission, they cannot list the buckets. The `s3:ListBuckets` permission allows users to list objects _within_ a bucket. It is badly named -- think of it as acting like `ListObjects` and things will be easier.

Comment: AWS should provide a mechanism that would allow a list of only the buckets authorized. perhaps a new permission, `s3:ListJustMyBuckets` or allow a resource(s) to be specified on the policy.
Or, rename `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` to `s3:ListAllBuckets` and create a new one, `s3:ListMyBuckets`